# Why does this animation make the screen wider on my iPad?

Tags: jquery, css

I've been having a play around with an animated top-bar on my new site. It works fine in Firefox, but not in IE/Chrome/Safari. Here is a JSFiddle of the code (for some reason it doesn't want to run here, but at least you can see what I'm doing)

http://jsfiddle.net/CHSS8/10/

**CSS:**

```
#sky-header {
  background: #5ba0f8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
#nav-bar-top {
  background: #228D00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
toggleSun();
setTimeout( function() { toggleCloud1(); },1000);
setTimeout( function() { toggleCloud2(); },2000);
function toggleSun() {
    $("#sun").animate({
        left: ($(document).width()/2)+"px"
        }, 10000, 'linear', function() {
            $("#sun").animate({
                left: ($(document).width()/2 - 30)+"px"
                }, 10000, 'linear', function() { toggleSun(); });
        });
}
function toggleCloud1() {
    $("#cloud1").animate({
        left: ($(document).width()+200)+"px"
        }, 50000, 'linear', function() {
            $("#cloud1").css('left',"-400px");
            toggleCloud1();
        });
}
function toggleCloud2() {
    $("#cloud2").animate({
        left: ($(document).width()+200)+"px"
        }, 43000, 'linear', function() {
            $("#cloud2").css('left',"-600px");
            toggleCloud2();
        });
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I'm floating the elements, and then doing `left` negative pixels, to make them go off the screen (before they go back to the beginning, and restart)

I know I can do this with CSS3 animations, but I couldn't get those working (nothing seemed to happen for some reason). I'm also not sure how easy it is to make an item go from one end to the other, even on different screens.

Comment: This fiddle doesnt work on Mozilla ,Chrome also

Comment: Sorry, I was missing some CSS. Please try this (I'll update the above link); http://jsfiddle.net/CHSS8/10/

Comment: You need `overflow:hidden;` for `#sky-header`

Comment: @BatuZet - ah man, how simple! Can't believe I missed that! Please add this as a proper answer, and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby yea actually sometimes the answer is right in front of our nose but we cant see it. Happens to all of us. Cheers ;)

Comment: @BatuZet - indeed! I spent AGES going over that (and I could have sworn I'd added in overflow hidden - but it looks like it did it just ont he `body`, and not the `#sky-header` div. Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `overflow:hidden;` for `#sky-header`